# DexException:Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/http/params/HttpParamConfig;

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-multidex

I recently updated android studio to 3.0.0 same for the gradle to the corresponding version, the gradle build successfully but I cant run my project anymore here is my gradle file

```
enter code here
buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
}

}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
mavenCentral()
google()
 }

  apply plugin: 'realm-android'

  android
    {
        signingConfigs {
            config {
                keyAlias 'XXXX'
                keyPassword 'XXXX'
                storeFile 
         file('/XXX/XXX/XXXX/XXX.jks')
                storePassword 'XXX'
            }
        }
        compileSdkVersion 26
        buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "www.XXX"
            minSdkVersion 23
            targetSdkVersion 26
            versionCode 46
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner 
            "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
            multiDexEnabled true
            vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
            javaCompileOptions {
                annotationProcessorOptions {
                    includeCompileClasspath false
                }
            }
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-
                android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                signingConfig signingConfigs.config
            }
        }
        dexOptions {
            javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
            preDexLibraries = false
        }
        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
            exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
        }
        configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy.force 
           'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
            all*.exclude group: 'org.apache.commons'

        }
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
    }

     dependencies {
     compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
     androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-
     core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
     })
    implementation project(':carpolo_sdk')
    implementation project(':material-sheet-fab')
implementation('org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.android.service:1.0.2') {
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
implementation 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3:1.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.4.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.6.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.3.9'
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.3.9'
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognito:2.3.9'
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognitoidentityprovider:2.3.9'
implementation 'io.saeid:fab-loading:0.6.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.4.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.4.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.4.2'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:2.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.4.2'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'
implementation 'com.github.florent37:singledateandtimepicker:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.github.apl-devs:appintro:v4.2.0'
implementation 'com.github.curioustechizen.android-ago:library:1.3.4'
implementation 'me.relex:circleindicator:1.2.2@aar'
implementation 'com.github.Mariovc:ImagePicker:1.2.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:22.0-android'
implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.7.1@aar') {
    transitive = true;
  }
 }
 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

My swagger gradle file contains the following

```
enter code here
dependencies {
compile "io.swagger:swagger-annotations:$swagger_annotations_version"
compile "com.google.code.gson:gson:$gson_version"
compile "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:$httpcore_version"
compile "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:$httpmime_version"
compile "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-
 android:$httpclient_version"
compile "com.android.volley:volley:${volley_version}"
testCompile "junit:junit:$junit_version"
testCompile "org.robolectric:robolectric:${robolectric_version}"
testCompile "net.jodah:concurrentunit:${concurrent_unit_version}"
```

}

I cant find whats wrong with my code any help would be appreciated .

Comment: In Android Studio, switch to the Project view (the view that shows the file structure, and normally says Android). Expand External libraries and see which ones are using the Apache lib. In your dependency list in build.gradle, exclude the Apache lib from one of the dependencies.

Comment: @fejd hey man can u check my edit answer and relate your answer please

Answer (score 0):

Turns out libraries were mixed together since I did the update to solve that I deleted the .idea folder then I clean and rebuild the project and the error was resolved.